# Android get a response from a HTTP request using Volley

Tags: java, android

I am trying to refactor my code. So I have the following:

1. Main `LoginActivity`

   ```
     private Boolean userauthenticated;

     onTryLogin(){  //login method executed after button click and validation

      JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
       try {
          postparams.put("username", login_username.getText());
          postparams.put("password", login_password.getText());
          postparams.put("client_secret", ApiHelper.PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET);
          postparams.put("grant_type", ApiHelper.PASSORT_GRANT_TYPE);
         postparams.put("client_id", ApiHelper.PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

    AuthService loginhelper = new AuthService(this);
    userauthenticated = loginhelper.login(loginurl, postparams);

    if(userauthenticated){
       //this is always false never executed even when its true
     }
   }
   ```

So my AuthService class has

```
public class AuthService {
     private Context ctx;
     private Boolean userloggedin = false;

      public AuthService(Context cnt){
        ctx = cnt;
     }

   public boolean  login(String loginurl, JSONObject loginparams){

      JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
              (Request.Method.POST, loginurl, loginparams,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            //set access tokens here
                            Log.i("test","successifully"+response);
                            userloggedin = true;
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    userloggedin = false;
                }
            }
            );


    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    ApiSingleton strngle = new ApiSingleton(ctx);
    strngle.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    return userloggedin;
  }

}
```

So from the above the check of

```
 if(userauthenticated){
 }
```

Always returns false. Even when in the AuthService class `onResponse` I have set the value to be true.
I am new to `Java` and I just had a look into Volley library. But I can't figure out how to pass the value from authservice class to the main login class.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when you do this:

```
userauthenticated = loginhelper.login(loginurl, postparams);
```

You're not considering that the `login()` function is an async function, therefore it will always return false, because that's the default value for the return in this function. You need to implement a callback structure. Something like:

```
public class AuthService {
     private Context ctx;
     private OnLoginCallback callback;
     private Boolean userloggedin = false;

      public AuthService(Context cnt){
        ctx = cnt;
        callback =(OnLoginCallback) cnt;
     }

   public boolean  login(String loginurl, JSONObject loginparams){

      JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
              (Request.Method.POST, loginurl, loginparams,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            //set access tokens here
                            Log.i("test","successifully"+response);
                            userloggedin = true;
                            callback.onLoginCallback(true);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    userloggedin = false;
                      callback.onLoginCallback(false);
                }
            }
            );


    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    ApiSingleton strngle = new ApiSingleton(ctx);
    strngle.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    return userloggedin;
  }

}


interface OnLoginCallback{
    void onLoginCallback(boolean loggedin);
}
```

Then in your activity you implement the interface `OnLoginCallback` and react to the `onLoginCallback()` method.

Comment: Thanks Levi, Am still new to java and android, Ive added OnLoginCallback interface as a new package, How will i let it communicate between my authservice and Main Login class to be notified when the value changes from true to false.

Comment: Just make you activity implement the interface (add `implements OnLoginCallback` to your activity). Then Android Studio will tell you that you need to implement the onLoginCallback(boolean logedin) mthod, you should implement it. When the callback from volley returns it should go to that method :)

Comment: Ive added it and now am getting a null pointer exception pointing to callback.onLoginCallback(false);

Comment: did you add this ` callback = (OnLoginCallback) cnt;` to the AuthService constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166625/discussion-between-levi-albuquerque-and-geoffrey-mwangi).